# GetSubBitmap() return empty bitmap on windows7

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wx.Bitmap's GetSubBitmap() API. On linux (ubuntu, fedora) everything OK. Trying to port code to windows7, GetSubBitmap() return empty bitmap, which result in black bitmap.

Here is simple example that draws periodically green rectangle somewhere on panel. On windows7 it turn to black rectangle.

```
import wx
import random

class mypanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(700, 500)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.ID_TIMER = 1
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, self.ID_TIMER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, id=self.ID_TIMER)
        self.timer.Start(1000, wx.TIMER_CONTINUOUS)
        self.BufferPaint()
        self.Refresh(False)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        print "OnTimerEvent " + str(event.Id)
        self.BufferPaint()

    def BufferPaint(self):
        dc = wx.MemoryDC()
        dc.SelectObject(self.buffer)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush("green"))
        dc.Clear()
        sub = self.buffer.GetSubBitmap(wx.Rect(5,5,30,30))
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush("red"))
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawBitmap(sub, random.randint(0,600), random.randint(0,400))
        self.Refresh(False)

    def OnPaint(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer)

class myframe(wx.Frame):

    """Draw a line to a panel."""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Draw on Panel", size=(800,600))
        self.panel1 = mypanel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = myframe(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def BufferPaint(self):
    dc = wx.MemoryDC()
    dc.SelectObject(self.buffer)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush("red"))
    dc.Clear()
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("green"))
    dc.DrawRectangleRect( wx.Rect(random.randint(0,600),random.randint(0,400),30,30) )
    self.Refresh(False)
```

I modified `BufferPaint` in your sample code to use `DrawRectangleRect` so that we explicitly paint with "green". Your code may be relying on default behavior how GetSubBitmap inherit the color which may be platform dependent.

My edit worked on my win7 machine.